# Function that shifts columns written in JavaScript not working in Google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function in javascript gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917492/shift-entire-columns-to-beginning-of-multidimensional-array-from-list-of-column)

I tried to put it into the proper format for Google sheets with the sparse knowledge I have but have not gotten it to work

The function shifts columns in an array from indices in a list
I am using chrome V8

The function gives the error `Cannot read property length of undefined` for
`sht2.getRange(1,1, result.length, result [0].length).setValues(result )`

Thanks

This is what id does

```
Bob|Carol|Ted|Alice
a  |b    |c  |d
1  |2    |3  |4
A  |B    |C  |D
```

If the list of indices is list=[3] so I get

```
Alice|Bob|Carol|Ted
d    |a  |b    |c
4    |1  |2    |3
D    |A  |B    |C
```

list = [2,3]

```
Ted|Alice|Bob|Carol
c  |d    |a  |b
3  |4    |1  |2
C  |D    |A  |B
```

```
function test() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht  = ss.getSheetByName('users');
  var rng  = sht.getDataRange();
  var data = rng.getValues();
  
  var tofront = [2,0,28,4]
  var result = rearrange(data, [2,0,28,4])

  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht2.getRange(1,1, result.length, result [0].length).setValues(result );
}


function rearrange(rows, tofront) {
 var rearrange = (rows=[], toFront=[]) => {

  var originalHeaders = [...rows[0]]

  var remainingHeaders = [...rows[0]]

  var frontHeaders = toFront.map(index => {
    // set this one to null, to be filtered out later
    remainingHeaders[index] = null
    // grab the original header value
    return originalHeaders[index]
  })
  // you don't want to modify the original headers directly,
  // seeing as you might not end up with the desired result
  // if you pass a `toFront` value like [1,2] or where
  // any of the values come after another
  
  var newHeaders = [
    ...frontHeaders,
    ...remainingHeaders.filter(v => v !== null)
  ]
  
  return data.map(r => {
    let row = {}
    r.forEach((value, i) => {
      row[originalHeaders[i]] = value
    })
    
    return newHeaders.map(h => row[h])
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: You're not writing back to the spreadsheet

Comment: sorry, just updated the function

Comment: `rearrange()` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're not returning anything from `rearrange()`. The other issue is that you're not actually executing the rearranging logic but actually just saving that function into the variable `rearrange`.

```
function rearrange(rows, tofront) {
 var rearrange = (rows=[], toFront=[]) => { /* rearranging logic */ }
 
 // Actually execute the logic and return its output
 return rearrange(rows, tofront);
}
```

There's no need to save the logic in the `rearrange` variable inside of the `rearrange()` function. You can just take that part out.

```
function test() {
  var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht  = ss.getSheetByName('users');
  var rng  = sht.getDataRange();
  var data = rng.getValues();
  
  var tofront = [2,3]
  var result = rearrange(data, tofront)

  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht2.getRange(1,1, result.length, result [0].length).setValues(result );
}


function rearrange(rows = [], toFront = []) {
  var originalHeaders = [...rows[0]]
  var remainingHeaders = [...rows[0]]

  var frontHeaders = toFront.map(index => {
    remainingHeaders[index] = null
    return originalHeaders[index]
  })
  
  var newHeaders = [
    ...frontHeaders,
    ...remainingHeaders.filter(v => v !== null)
  ]
  
  return rows.map(r => {
    let row = {}
    r.forEach((value, i) => {
      row[originalHeaders[i]] = value
    })
    
    return newHeaders.map(h => row[h])
  });
}
```

* You were also referencing `data` in your penultimate `map()`, but that should have been `rows` as indicated above.

Comment: This is sweat!! Thank you. Diego, why use `forEach`  and not `map` Thank you again

Comment: @Einarr Glad it works. I recommend that you ask the original author as I didn't inspect any of that at all.